# What tool does W3C use to render RDF files and documentation web pages?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web

The WCAT W3C page https://www.w3.org/TR/vocab-dcat-2/ is based in part on the RDF serialization of the DCAT RDF https://www.w3.org/ns/dcat2.ttl.

What is the tool that is used to create the W3C pages, and where is the source kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use [ReSpec](https://respec.org/docs); that page should look familiar to the vocab landing page. Looking at the HML, it looks like they're on `ReSpec 25.1.0`.

You can find the ReSpec source and config [here](https://github.com/w3c/dxwg/tree/gh-pages/ucr).

Comment: Did they just write out all of the specs, then? I thought that they were compiling the RDF into the HTML...

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the tools used depend on the spec authors' choices.

The examples on that page are held in this repository:
https://github.com/w3c/dxwg

The managers of that repository (I see overlaps with the spec authors) might be able to answer your question. I could not spot anything identifying a specific tool.